# filter results by month on button click with Angujar

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to wrap my head around angular still, I started learning a few days ago, and I am still getting to know Angular. I've been trying to experiment with a simple json http request. So far, I have succesfully grabbed and displayed the data, I have implemented a directive inside my controller with your basic search input and a few select options for more filtering based on their value.

However, I want to filter the results even more, by simply clicking on buttons with Month names, therefore filtering the results by the month in their date

**My index.html:**

```
<div ng-app="myNetworkEvents">
  <div ng-controller="networkEventsCtrl">
    <networkevent-directive></networkevent-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My template:**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="event in events | filter:search | myFilter:monthlyFilter">
    <p>{{event.title}}</p>
    <p>{{event.date}}</p>
    <p>{{event.tickets}}</p>
    <p>{{event.body}}</p>
  </li>
  <li ng-show="(events | filter:search).length==0">Couldn't find "{{search}}"</li>
</ul>

<!-- my search box -->
<input ng-model="search" type="search">

<!-- filter by month -->
<ul ng-model="monthlyFilter">
  <li><a>January</a></li>
  <li><a>February</a></li>
  <li><a>March</a></li>
</ul>
```

**My app.js**:

```
angular.module('myNetworkEvents', ['ui.utils'])

.service('networkEvents', function ($http, $q) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('url to api').then(function (data){
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });
  this.getNetworkEvents = function (){
    return deferred.promise;
  }
})

.controller('networkEventsCtrl', function ($scope, networkEvents) {
  var getNetworkEvents = networkEvents.getNetworkEvents();
  getNetworkEvents.then(function (eventsData){       
    $scope.events = eventsData.data;
  });
})

.directive('networkeventDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "networkevents.html"
  }
})

//this is where i have no idea what to do besides this
.filter('myFilter',['$filter', function($filter){
  return function(list){
    return list;
  }
}])
```

**Sample of what my json looks like:**

```
{
body: "Some awesomesauce here"
date: "4/3/2015 9:48:04 AM"
id: "207"
isactive: "Yes"
thumbnailurl: ""
tickets: "100"
title: "A nice event"
}
```

Comment: Add the ability to take in filter params so once you selected a month, it sets a scope property to that month. From there, it should hit your filter and change the filtered list.

Comment: Try to simplify your code - is absolutely everything there needed to repro your issue? Do you a need a directive or you can you just put the stuff in the controller/View? Do you need `$http` or can you just assign the data?